# populate not returning refs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two schemas,

```
// Post.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  likes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "postLike"
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model("post", postSchema);
```

and

```
//PostLike.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postLikeSchema = new Schema({
  post: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "post"
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  // Flag to denote like or dislike
  likeOrDislike: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = PostLike = mongoose.model("postLike", postLikeSchema);
```

When I upvote a post, it saves it in `PostLike` like this:

[image: img1]

But when I try to retrieve the post

```
let post = await Post.find({ _id: id }).populate("likes");

console.log(post);

return res.json(post);
```

It returns likes array with length 0,

```
 [ likes: [],
 date: 2019-09-03T07:03:02.481Z,
 user: 5d495163bd47260574dff2c4,
 __v: 0 } ]
```

Not sure where to go from here. I've tried to populate with `.populate("postLike");` but that didn't work either. In the method where I save a like or dislike, do I also have to do `Post.findOneAndUpdate(...)`? Because that eliminates the whole point of having refs in the schemas.

Comment: Unless you save likeId in post schema you can't populate it as it's an empty array or you can just do aggregate on likes db->match post id->group on post id and push details in an array or as per your needs->lookup post to get it's details populated

Comment: So what's the point of `ref`? Instead of `likes: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "postLike" } ]` I can just do `likes: [ { type: String, required: true } ]`

Comment: are you saving likes objectids in post likes array if yes it'll automatically fetch ref from likes collection if not saving ids how'll it fetch referenced objectId from likes collection?